# How can I model this distorted torus?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to model a ring that is styled following this reference:

[image]

I'd like to make the distortions using geometry nodes and/or other modifiers such that they can be animated. Thinking the animation would probably be done by transforming the coordinate space of a texture, but I'm not sure what kind of modeling technique to follow for making the distorted hooky bits.

I wondered about doing this with shaders, i.e. a solid torus geometry with parts knocked off with transparency to achieve the effect. I feel it's probably doable with actual geometry though.

**Edit:** trying to improve on the vagueness, the specific thing that I'm stuck on is how to model the features circled below.

[image]

They look a bit like what the snake hook sculpting brush might be good for, but I'd like achieve them with nodes and/or modifiers.

Comment: Your description of what you want to achieve is rather vague... But what I can already tell you is that transparency isn't gonna work. The reason is that it will just cause holes in the mesh and not parts knocked off as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you just want to move certain vertices of a ring outward and offset them radially, right?

...At least it looks like that on the picture. If I am wrong, please be so kind and clarify the question.

If I am correct, you could solve it as follows:

[image]

Use `Curve to Mesh` to create a ring.

Randomly select some vertices of the mesh with the node `Random Value` (set to *Boolean*).

Move them outwards along their normals, and rotate this vector a bit around the center.

*I've made it a little more extreme than necessary, just to illustrate it better.*

[image]

Comment: This is great considering how vague my question was :-}. It might be tricky to animate, but definitely give be a good base to start playing with!